Volume control of speaker playing from bluetooth device via Polaris NB IoT board
I have a Polaris NB IoT board. I wish to connect it to a speaker that plays music via a bluetooth module. I currently have this bluetooth module with a CSR8645 chip, which I can connect to my TPA3116 amplifier and play music, however I wish to set a varying maximum volume from my Polaris board based on GPS data. How can I accomplish this? I have read about RX/TX pins which can send such information but my module does not seem to have these. I am open to acquiring new hardware for this purpose. Thanks in advance!

please edit your question ... add information about the chip on the Bluetooth module ... the website you linked does not say anything about it

You are aware that GPS modules all output similar messages which are defined by the industry and have to be picked through to find information like latitude or time or satellite signal strength or the location of a satellite in the sky. So, there's a lot to pick through.  It isn't trivial to listen to all those messages, pick out the ones you are interested in and some how control the volume of another device depending on where you are in the world. The serial ports you are talking about are likely on that Quectel L76 – GPS/GLONASS Receiver inside your Polaris.

@st2000 The GPS data I already have a solution for, I just need to be able to adjust the volume playing on the speaker via my board

Understood. So, your links point to web pages that don't help very much "This is a "maker" module ... without any further instructions than what you find here". The amp looks like it has pots to control the volume. You would have to UN-solder and replace them with some type of digital pot chip and interface that (probably w/I2C) from your Polaris. The pictures for the BT module don't even match. So I don't know if there are or are not volume switches on the BT board. That might have been simpler. But who knows what version you have. Maybe there's a way through the A2DP BT protocol.

@st2000 My apologies, I did not realise they were different. I have the one on the first image with the buttons on the side

I could amend my answer to accomodate. However, simulating a button press would require hardware knowledge (what chips to use and how to solder) as well as embedded software knowledge (maybe how to communicate over I2C from the Polaris if that is even possible). Even if that is the type of answer you are looking for, I don't have a Polaris board so can only create an answer which suggest approaches. Not a complete design.

As the processor based Polaris NB IoT board is to control volume consider adding a digital pot between the Bluetoot sound source and the TPA3116 amplifier.
There are many digital pot integrated circuits available (as seen on this digital pot filtered Digikey web page). All of which would take some electrical engineering knowledge to integrate into an existing design.
Consider searching for project like this one where an amplifier is built with a digital pot. Such a design might be used for the bases of adding a digital pot between an existing sound source and amplifier.

I used a digital amplifier (MCP41010) to connect my Bluetooth module, board and amplifier and it works I am now able to adjust the volume of my speaker using SPI and GPIO commands. Thank you for your help!

Excellent! Glad it worked.
